# Adding two identical select2 forms to same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2

I am trying to add two [select2 multi-value select boxes](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to my Rails app.

The top form works fine, but the bottom one does not work.

I experimented with changing ids and adding new js code, but no success. Is there something fundamentally wrong that I'm missing?

**Index.html**

```
# This one works fine
<div class="search_genre">Genre:</div>
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi populate">
    <select multiple="" name="e9" id="e9" style="width:300px" class="populate select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Search or Select">
       <optgroup label="Popular">
           <option value="Alt">Rock</option>
           <option value="Ind">Indie</option>
           <option value="Ind">Alternative</option>
           <option value="Ind">Acoustic</option>
       </optgroup>
      </select>
</div>


# This one doesn't show a text input or the optiongroup values
<div class="search_region">Region:</div>
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi populate">
    <select multiple="" name="e9" id="e9" style="width:300px" class="populate select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1" placeholder="Search or Select">
       <optgroup label="Local">
           <option value="PDX">Greater Portland</option>
           <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
           <option value="WA">Washington</option>
       </optgroup>
      </select>
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
$("#e9").select2();
```

Comment: It's hopefully just a cut/paste error but you have the same value for three of your options in you "this one works fine" code snippet. `value="Ind"` x3

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65194682/8919282

Answer (score 11):

You can not have two elements with the same `id`. Use classes instead.

Both your selects have `id="e9"` instead try adding something like `class="my-select"` to your `<select>` element.

then do `$('.my-select').select2();`

Answer (score 5):

For each select2 in the same page you must define unique id for tag "data-select2-id".

```
data-select2-id="Project"
```

and

```
data-select2-id="WBSDate"
```

Comment: Thanks. its helped me. I am searching for several days for this. but for me something is differendt i had same id. so i changed the id and its works fine.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ramy Mention. I hope its works fine for everyone.
If It won't work then try this.
In select box you can't use same id for an example:

```
       <select class="form-control select2" id="select">
           <option>Select</option> 
           <option>Cycle</option> 
           <option>Horse</option> 
        </select>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="select">
           <option>Select</option> 
           <option>Cycle</option> 
           <option>Horse</option> 
        </select>
```

If you have same id the search box won't work.
Just try to different Id Name like below.

```
       <select class="form-control select2" id="select">
           <option>Select</option> 
           <option>Cycle</option> 
           <option>Horse</option> 
        </select>
        <select class="form-control select2" id="select1">
           <option>Select</option> 
           <option>Cycle</option> 
           <option>Horse</option> 
        </select>
```

I faced this kind of problem. That's why i shared here my opinion.
Thanks hope someone will get help from this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was something fundamental!

The id's were both the same. This seemed odd to me, and was the first thing that I changed to see if it would work. I added a new jquery code to application.js with id #e10 and changed teh second form's id accordingly. Yesterday, this didn't work. However, today it did. I must have missed something silly, like saving the page...

I wish SO allowed you to delete answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using identical data-select2-id property solve the problem.

MVC input helpers throws sytax error for hyphen, replace the hyphen with underscore, and salute.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.WIds, WList, new { @class = "form-control opWflWafers", @multiple = "multiple", data_select2_id=identicalname })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="float-left col-sm-3">
<select class="form-control" id="parentesco" name="parentesco[]" required></select>
</div>
<script>
      $('#parentesco*').select2({
        placeholder: 'Seleccionar paciente',
        ajax: {
          url: 'ajax_paciente.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });
     
</script>
```

Comment: Please, especially when answering to old questions with already upvoted answers, avoid code-only answers. Explain the principle, and what new idea, absent from previous answers it provides.